# My javascript is not working with my page in asp.net

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

Recently I am working on asp.net application but my found that my script is not working and don't know why even I tested in the fiddle.

I want my list box to be filtered when user key in any keyword in the textbox.

My list box ID is "ItemList".

My textbox ID is "txtSearchItem".

here is my script for the page:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Staff/Staff.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="AddPackage.aspx.cs" Inherits="ExpressPrintingSystem.Staff.Owner.Package.AddPackage" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
    <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document.getElementById("<%=txtSearchItem.ClientID%>")).on("keyup", function () {
                var search = this.value;
                $("option", document.getElementById("<%= ItemList.ClientID %>")).show().filter(function () {
                    return $(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(search.toLowerCase()) < 0;
                }).hide();
            }); 
    </script>
</asp:Content>
```

Here is the ListBox with is located in a table:

```
<td><asp:TextBox ID="txtSearchItem" TextMode="Search" Width="200px" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static"/><br />
                    <asp:ListBox ID="ItemList" runat="server" Width="200px" DataSourceID="sdsItem" ClientIDMode="static" DataTextField="ItemName" DataValueField="ItemID"></asp:ListBox>
                    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="sdsItem" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:printDBServer %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [ItemID], [ItemName] FROM [Item] WHERE ([ItemID] LIKE '%' + @keyword + '%')  OR ([ItemName] LIKE '%' + @keyword + '%')">
                    <SelectParameters>
                        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="txtSearchItem" DefaultValue="I" Name="keyword" PropertyName="Text" />
                    </SelectParameters>
                    </asp:SqlDataSource>
                </td>
```

I not sure where is the error occur. I want the option tag to be hidden when the keywords in the text box is not match with the keywords user type in. The ListBox is linked with a datasource which will call all the record of the item out. Please help me.

Here is my whole complete code:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Staff/Staff.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="AddPackage.aspx.cs" Inherits="ExpressPrintingSystem.Staff.Owner.Package.AddPackage" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
    <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document.getElementById("<%=txtSearchItem.ClientID%>")).on("keyup", function () {
                var search = this.value;
                $("option", document.getElementById("<%= ItemList.ClientID %>")).show().filter(function () {
                    return $(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(search.toLowerCase()) < 0;
                }).hide();
            }); 
    </script>
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="cphStaffContent" runat="server">
    <h1>Add Package</h1>
    <asp:Label ID="lblError" runat="server" ForeColor="Red" Text=""></asp:Label>

        <table>
            <tr>
                <td><asp:Label ID="lblName" runat="server" Text="Name:"></asp:Label></td>
                <td><asp:TextBox ID="txtName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td>
                <td><asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvName" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtName" ForeColor="Red" ErrorMessage="Please fill up the the Name field."></asp:RequiredFieldValidator></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><asp:Label ID="lblSupport" runat="server" Text="Support Files:"></asp:Label></td>
                <td><asp:CheckBoxList ID="cblSupport" runat="server"></asp:CheckBoxList></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><asp:Label ID="lblType" runat="server" Text="Type of Package:"></asp:Label></td>
                <td><asp:DropDownList ID="ddlType" runat="server" Height="17px" Width="128px"></asp:DropDownList></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><asp:Label ID="lblItems" runat="server" Text="Package's Items:"></asp:Label></td>
                <td><asp:Table ID="tblPackageItems" runat="server" Width="100%"> 
                        <asp:TableRow>
                            <asp:TableCell>Item</asp:TableCell>
                            <asp:TableCell>Quantity</asp:TableCell>
                        </asp:TableRow>
                    </asp:Table> </td>
                <td><asp:TextBox ID="txtSearchItem" TextMode="Search" Width="200px" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static"/><br />
                    <asp:ListBox ID="ItemList" runat="server" Width="200px" DataSourceID="sdsItem" ClientIDMode="static" DataTextField="ItemName" DataValueField="ItemID"></asp:ListBox>
                    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="sdsItem" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:printDBServer %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [ItemID], [ItemName] FROM [Item] WHERE ([ItemID] LIKE '%' + @keyword + '%')  OR ([ItemName] LIKE '%' + @keyword + '%')">
                    <SelectParameters>
                        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="txtSearchItem" DefaultValue="I" Name="keyword" PropertyName="Text" />
                    </SelectParameters>
                    </asp:SqlDataSource>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><asp:Label ID="lblEstPrice" runat="server" Text="Estimated Price (RM):"></asp:Label></td>
                <td><asp:Label ID="lblEstimatedPrice" runat="server" Text="0"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><asp:Label ID="lblPrice" runat="server" Text="Package Price (RM):"></asp:Label></td>
                <td><asp:TextBox ID="txtPrice" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td>
            </tr>    
        </table>
            <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Add Package"/>
            <asp:Button ID="btnCancel" runat="server" Text="Cancel"/>
</asp:Content>
```

This is my master page:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Staff.master.cs" Inherits="ExpressPrintingSystem.Staff.Staff" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Staff Portal</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/styles/main.css" type="text/css" />
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="page">
        <form runat="server">
        <div id="header">
            <asp:SiteMapDataSource ID="SiteMapDataSourceForStaff" SiteMapProvider="StaffSiteMap" runat="server" ShowStartingNode="false" />
            <div>
            <a href="#" class="logo"><img src="<%=Page.ResolveUrl("~/Images/logo/long_logo.png")%>" alt=""/></a>
            <ul id="navigation">
                    <li class="selected">
                        <a href="#">Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="menu" DataSourceID="SiteMapDataSourceForStaff">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <li>
                                <asp:HyperLink runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("Url") %>'><%# Eval("Title") %></asp:HyperLink>

                                <asp:Repeater runat="server" DataSource='<%# ((SiteMapNode) Container.DataItem).ChildNodes %>'>
                                    <HeaderTemplate>
                                        <ul>
                                    </HeaderTemplate>

                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <li>
                                            <asp:HyperLink runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("Url") %>'><%# Eval("Title") %></asp:HyperLink>
                                        </li>
                                    </ItemTemplate>

                                    <FooterTemplate>
                                        </ul>
                                    </FooterTemplate>
                                </asp:Repeater>
                            </li>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:Repeater>
                    <li style="float:right;">
                        <asp:HyperLink ID="userInfoControl" runat="server"/>

                        <ul id="userMenu" runat="server">

                        </ul>
                    </li>               </ul>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="content">
            <div>
                <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="cphStaffContent" runat="server">

                </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
            </div>

        </div>
    </form>
        <footer id="footer">
            <div class="footcontent">
                <div>
                    <a href="#" class="logo"><img src="<%=Page.ResolveUrl("~/Images/logo/long_logo.png")%>" alt=""/></a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="footnote">
                <div>
                    <p>&copy; 2017 BY Express Printing System | ALL RIGHTS RESERVED</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </footer>
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What error are you getting that you know it is not working?

Comment: actually there is no error. just the function is not working

Comment: Is there no error on the Web Page when you inspect with console in the browser?

Comment: No, actually is my fault because I did't know that jquery library is needed to include in the webpage for the things to work. Thank for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This kind of problem is usually encountered when there are conflicts between jQuery and other libraries. To stay out of trouble, call `$.noConflict()` and don't forget to run your jQuery code after the document is ready

```
$.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function($){ /**/});
```

Comment: I added like this. but is not working
<script type="text/javascript">
        $.noConflict();
        jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
            $(document.getElementById("<%=txtSearchItem.ClientID%>")).on("keyup", function () {
                var search = this.value;
                $("option", document.getElementById("<%= ItemList.ClientID %>")).show().filter(function () {
                    return $(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(search.toLowerCase()) < 0;
             }).hide();
            }); 
        });
    </script>

Comment: Anything else that I can check to find the problem?

Comment: instead of `$(document.getElementById("targetedId"))` use `$("#targetedId")`. You can try to debug with simple alerts to see if your script is getting executed or not

Comment: `$("#targetedId").autocomplete({ source: [ ] });`

Comment: if you are using jqury-ui

Comment: I found that I use other person jsfiddle to do my code testing and found that he is using a library, so that's why the code is working. This is how I found my problem when I redo the jsfiddle by my own to show you guy the code I am testing.

Comment: Thank you for all the help. It work well after I include the library

Answer (score 0):

First create a JavaScript file instead of a `script` tag and than link that file in the master page like this:

```
<script src="<%=ResolveClientUrl("~/content/assets/vendor/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js")%>">
</script>
```